# How to make button link to path in HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I originally had just a button that when clicked would direct the user to a different path. Here is the code for that:

```
  .bar
    %h1.pull-left= t('payer_contracts.payer_contracts')
    = button_to t('payer_contracts.new_payer_contract'), new_payer_contract_path, {:class => 'btn pull-right', :method => 'get'}
```

Now, I have a button that is a button dropdown. How exactly can I add a path to the first button "Add Global Payer Contract" and then a different path to the button drop down option "Add BPCI Payer Contract"?

```
  .bar
    .btn-group.dropdown-end
      %button.btn{:type => "button"} Add Global Payer Contract
      %button.btn.icon-decrement{"aria-expanded" => "false", "aria-haspopup" => "true", "data-toggle" => "dropdown", :type => "button"}
      %ul{"aria-hidden" => "true", :role => "menu"}
        %li
          %a{:href => "#"} Add BPCI Payer Contract
```

I am wanting to path "Add Global Payer Contract" to new_payer_contract_path
and add BPCI Payer Contract to add_new_bpci_path

Answer (score 3):

You would use [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to).

[`button_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) despite the name does not really mean that you should use it when you want to have a link which looks like a button. `button_to` creates a discrete form, which makes it ideal for buttons which perform POST, DELETE or PATCH operations since it makes it possible even without javascript tomfoolery.

```
button_to "Delete", thing_path(@thing), method: :delete
```

However its totally overkill when you just want a link to a new, index or show action. If you use `button_to` everywhere you will get a very heavy and convoluted document (think .Net WebForms).

```
  .bar
    .btn-group.dropdown-end
      %button.btn{:type => "button"} Add Global Payer Contract
      %button.btn.icon-decrement{"aria-expanded" => "false", "aria-haspopup" => "true", "data-toggle" => "dropdown", :type => "button"}
      %ul{"aria-hidden" => "true", :role => "menu"}
        %li
          = link_to "Add BPCI Payer Contract", new_payer_contract_path
```

Comment: Awesome. This works, but how would I link a path to the "Add Global Payer Contract"?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Comment: I still can't get it right. Any ideas? I've tried this: %button.btn{:type => "button"} Add Global Payer Contract
      = link_to t('payer_contracts.new_payer_contract'), new_payer_contract_path

Comment: I don't think you really get what I'm saying - don't use a `<button>` element either. You should be using an anchor (link) `<a>` element. Thats what link_to() creates. You then use CSS to style it so that it "looks like a button".  `= link_to t('payer_contracts.new_payer_contract'), new_payer_contract_path, class: 'btn'`